# How to apply this style

Tags: html, css

In my website, text is dynamically appended to the page.

My need if the `td` has attribute has `colspan=2`, apply `text-align:center`.

```
tblCustomers tr td 
{
   padding-left:25px;
}
//how do I do this
tblCustomer tr td:hasattribute(colspan=2)
{
   text-align:center;
}
```

**Note:-**

- No suggestion for adding class or id. Its not feasible in my scenario.
- No JavaScript or jQuery for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this way

```
tblCustomers tr td {
  padding-left:25px;
}

tblCustomers tr td[colspan="2"] {
 text-align:center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nsse87c4/

Comment: Yes. It meets my requirement. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add this style , make sure to define this `tblCustomer` `class` or `id` , for eg: I've put this as `class`

```
.tblCustomer tr td[colspan="2"]{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to apply a style to all td's with a specific colspan, you can use the following selector:

```
td[colspan="2"]
```

or more specifically:

```
td[colspan="2"]{
   text-align:center;
}
```

source: https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/PR-CSS2-19980324/selector.html

Answer (score 0):

[Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation)

> CSS2 introduced four attribute selectors:
>
> …
>
> `[att=val]`
>   Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is exactly "val".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
tblCustomer tr td[colspan="2"]
{
   text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just added `width: 100%` to your table so you see visualize the effect properly.

```css
.tblCustomer
{
  width: 100%;
}
.tblCustomer tr td[colspan="2"]
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table class="tblCustomer">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```